# Text Box Values got lost in ASP.NET page load Event

Tags: asp.net

currently i was working in **asp.net web application .**
In asp page i was assign values to all controls on page load event using the Query string value.
On Compiling with break point i was able to see **the values in the text box** and other controls.But after completing the Page load event all **my assigned values for the text boxes** **got lost.**

Help me to solve this issue

Comment: There is definitely a bug in your code, which no one can solve unless you show it.

Comment: @nunespascal  Thanks for your reply i was checked my code. Only the text box assigned value got lost .
I was put all my controls under UpdatePanel but i was not able to display values in the text box after Page load completed

Comment: it means your update panel not updated your UI

Comment: post your update panel code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in ASP page

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidtext" runat="server" value="">
```

in JScript

```
    <script>
document.getElementById("hidtext").value = document.getElementById("textbox1")
.value;
    </script>
```

after post back

```
textbox1.text=hidtext.value;
```